# How to find the percentage of $\bar{X}\pm S$?

Tags: probability, statistics

How to find the percentage of $\bar{X}\pm S$ in the table

[image]

The solution is given as

[image]

[image]

then

[image]

the percentage is

[image]

My question is where does the equation

[image]

come from?

Comment: a little context would help

Comment: My guess is that the actual question is to find the proportion of the observations that fall into the interval $\bar X \pm S.$ If the data are 'mound shaped' (vague language for roughly normal), then the Empirical Rule says the answer is often around 68% (so the 65% found here is 'about right'). The last equation about which OP asks seems to be a way to interpolate to find the proportion in the the interval mentioned, necessary because data seem to have been put into six bins in such a way that interpolation is necessary.

Answer (score 0):

**Comment on the Empirical Rule** (possibly helpful but not intended to be an answer).

In a normal population, about 68% of the probability is found within one standard deviation of the mean. That is, if $X \sim Norm(\mu, \sigma),$ then
$P(\mu - \sigma < X \le \mu + \sigma) = \Phi(-1) - \Phi(+1) = 0.6826,$ as can be found from printed tables.

In a sample from the normal population, there is no guarantee that 68% of the data values will fall within $\bar X \pm S$. This is because $\bar X$ is an estimate of $\mu$ and $S$ is an estimate of $\sigma$ (neither estimate guaranteed perfect)
and the data in a small sample may not yield a histogram that looks much like
a normal density curve.

Nevertheless, it is often a useful rough rule-of-thumb to say that about
2/3 of data fall between $\bar X - S$ and $\bar X + S.$ The larger the
sample, the better the chances this will be nearly true.

This is often called the *Empirical Rule* (ER). There are 2 and 3 standard deviation
versions of it, that follow similar logic: About 95% of observations fall
within $\bar X \pm 2S$, and "all or nearly all" (approximately 99.7%)
of observations fall within $\bar X \pm 3S.$

Many elementary texts present a dataset suitably contrived so that
all three versions of the Empirical Rule are approximately right. Instances
in the real world of such good adherence to the ER are somewhat more rare,
but the rule has its uses.

One use of the ER is that it helps motivate the concept of standard deviation,
about which few beginning students have good intuition. For example, if I
walk into a classroom and say that I guess the average height of students
in the room is about 57", that seems about right to most students.

But if I
say it looks to me that the SD of their heights is about 1", then the
ER puts that guess in doubt. It really does not seem right to say that
95% of the students should have heights between 55" and 59". Maybe a guess
that the SD is around 3.5" is more credible.

(This would be a better
example, if heights of all students were actually normal, but there is
a slight difference between average heights of men and women, so the
population distribution is a 'mixture' distribution with larger SD than
for a normal distribution.  This example also has the potential to
embarrass any really tall or really short students in the class.)